# How to add a jumper in Orcad Capture?

Tags: components, library, jumper, orcad

I am making a schematic of a PCB in Orcad Capture. I have to place a jumper. Does anyone know the part number for a jumper or the library where it can be found?

Comment: What do you mean by jumper?  A 2 pin header that can be shorted on the board, or a symbol that allows you to assign multiple names to the same schematic net?

Comment: Why not create your own part? It would only take a minute or so with the PCB software I use.

Answer (score 1):

In Orcad Capture the jumper symbols are contained in the "CONNECTOR" library.

If this library has not yet been added to your project, this is how you find it:

1. Open the "Place Part" sidebar.
2. Open the "Search for Part" section at the bottom.
3. Search for "JUMPER*".
4. Double click any of the elements found to add the "CONNECTOR" library to your project.